# Is there a way to give each variable in a list to hold tk.IntVar()?

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to know how to shorten the code (below) by using a list:

```
photo_name = tk.IntVar()
lat = tk.IntVar()
lon = tk.IntVar()
ts = tk.IntVar()
gps_lat_r = tk.IntVar()
gps_lat = tk.IntVar()
gps_lon_r = tk.IntVar()
gps_lon = tk.IntVar()
gps_img_d_r = tk.IntVar()
gps_img_d = tk.IntVar()
gps_info = tk.IntVar()
```

What I have tried:

```
meta_data = [
    photo_name, lat, lon, ts, gps_lat_r, gps_lat, gps_lon_r, gps_lon, gps_img_d_r, gps_img_d, gps_info
]

x = 0
for c in meta_data:
    c[x] = tk.IntVar()
    x = x + 1
```

However an error returns 'name 'photo_name' is not defined.

Comment: Your existing code is fine. Don't try to create dynamic variables. Even though there are hackish ways to implement that, it's more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: @Selcuk thanks for your reply, I assume it would be through the __init__ class? For this example in particular, I agree, it isn't worth the trouble. It was a question that spawned out of curiosity :)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `__init__` class but no, it's done using `locals()` or `globals()` dictionaries. Search for "python dynamic variables" in Stack Overflow and you will find lots of (bad) advice regarding how to implement that.

Comment: if you want to make it with `for`-loop then you need list with strings `meta_data = [ "photo_name", ...]` and dictionary for variables - `variables = dict()` and create them `variables[c] = tk.IntVar()`.  But later you would have to use `variables["photo_name"]` to access it. But in some situations it is good solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution works for the question.

```
meta_data = [
    'photo_name', 'lat', 'lon', 'ts', 'gps_lat_r', 'gps_lat', 'gps_lon_r', 'gps_lon', 'gps_img_d_r', 'gps_img_d', 'gps_info'
]

variables = dict()

for c in meta_data:
    variables[c] = tk.IntVar()
```